# Montreal - Ottawa night connection at Sunday

Tags: canada, night-transport, montreal, ottawa

How I can reach Ottawa from Montreal at the later evening (approximately from 22:00 or even 23:00) at Sunday? Does some public connection (train, night bus or something else) exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are Greyhound buses leaving Montreal at 21:00 and 00:00 every night of the week, arriving Ottawa at 23:30 and 2:50 respectively.